# Natural ranged weapon damage confusion

Tags: d6-system

According to the book the damage for a natural ranged weapon is:

> The damage for physically enhanced projections is the
>   character’s Strength Damage plus 1D per rank, while the
>   damage for all other types of blasts is 3D per rank.

Now what I'm not getting is Strength based damage here. Is it +1D per rank or (STRENGTH damage + 1D) per rank?

Answer (score 2):

1) RAW it's syntactically ambiguous.  This is because of the grammar of the English language: "One pie and one apple per child" can mean (apparently) either (one pie and one apple) per child or one pie and (one apple per child).  The rule isn't dealt with anywhere else so either interpretation is valid.

2) In terms of game design, the game does NOT intend you to apply your strength damage manipulatively with rank.  At ranks much larger than two the gap between expected defenses and the damage that sort of multiplicative application of strength can do becomes quite apparent.